# Auto-size view with dynamic font in enclosed textview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

So here's one I just can't seem to find a matching case for in searching on here.

I have a small UIView that contains a UITextView, and the UIView needs to auto-size around the TextView for presentation over another view. Basically the TextView needs to fully fill the UIView, and the UIView should only be big enough to contain the TextView.

The TextView just contains a couple sentences that are meant to stay on the screen until an external thing happens, and certain values change.

Everything is great when I used a fixed-size font.

But hey... I'm an old guy, and I have the text size jacked up a bit on my phone. Testing it on my device shows where I must be missing something.

When using the dynamic font style "Title 2" in the textview properties, and turning on "Automatically adjust font" in the TextView properties, and having the text larger than the default, it seems as if I'm not properly capturing the size of the TextView's growth (with the bigger text) when creating the new bounding rect to toss at the frame. It's returning values that look a lot like the smaller, default-size text values rather than the increased text size.

Code is below, the view's class code as well as the calling code (made super explicit for posting here). I figure I'm either missing something silly like capturing the size after something happens to the fonts, but even moving this code to a new function and explicitly calling it after the controls fully draw doesn't seem to do it.

I hope this make sense.

Thanks, all.

Calling code:

```
let noWView:NoWitnessesYetView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NoWitnessesYetView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! NoWitnessesYetView)
//if nil != noWView {
let leftGutter:CGFloat = 20.0
let bottomGutter:CGFloat = 24.0
let newWidth = self.view.frame.width - ( leftGutter + leftGutter )
let newTop = (eventMap.frame.minY + eventMap.frame.height) - ( noWView.frame.height + bottomGutter ) // I suspect here is the issue
// I suspect that loading without drawing is maybe not allowing 
// the fonts to properly draw and the 
// TextView to figure out the size...?
noWView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: newTop, width: newWidth, height: noWView.frame.height)
self.view.addSubview(noWView)
//}
```

Class code:

```
import UIKit
class NoWitnessesYetView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: EyeneedRoundedTextView!
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let newWidth = self.frame.width
        // form up a dummy size just to get the proper height for the popup
        let workingSize:CGSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        // then build the real newSize value
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: workingSize.height)
        textView.frame.size = newSize
        self.textView.isHidden = false
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // .blue
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This perfect way to do it the content comes from : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jb29c22xu8 .

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's create our text view
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
        textView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        textView.text = "Here is some default text that we want to show and it might be a couple of lines that are word wrapped"

        view.addSubview(textView)

        // use auto layout to set my textview frame...kinda
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
            ].forEach{ $0.isActive = true }

        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)

        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false

        textViewDidChange(textView)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the tutorial, and I've bookmarked it for later perusal when I've got a block of time to watch it. Thanks. Right now I'm trying to find out if I've missed a simple thing, or if I'm just taking the completely wrong approach. I won't be able to watch the video until later this evening.

Comment: your will never regret :) . he will give the logic behind this.